# How to improve shadow quality in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, light

I have several object in a scene. And I want them moving on a wide plane, which will receive shadows. If I use only one point light or a very large directional light the shadow of a object when it moved to the corner will become very rough (rough shadow edge) . like this:
[image: shadow with rough edge]

So I’m wondering should I use a light for every object above them and follow them in order to cast a high quality shadow edge? And in some case I can not set the shadow.mapsize higher .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of things that control shadow quality.

What it looks like to me, is your shadow cameras left / right / top / bottom are set too large, and its casting the shadow over too large an area.

Shadow casting lights are pretty expensive, so I would avoid trying to compensate by having multiple lights.

Try reducing the light.shadow.camera left/right/top/bottom to focus the map better on where you're objects are. Also trying increasing shadowmap size to something like 1024 or 2048 square.

Another thing that helps is to use THREE.PCFShadowmapping instead of the default. That will smooth the edges of your shadows.

edit: Also check out PCFSoftShadowMapping.. slower to render, but greatly smooths shadow edges.

Getting the shadow mapping right is a tricky process and requires a lot of fiddling.

Also, try attaching a DirectionalLightHelper to your light and also a CameraHelper to the lights camera. Those will help you figure out how big the shadow casting area is and where things are pointing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQz2Z.jpg

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the method you mentioned in codepen.https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/jzrzge.
So, the best solution for me is to set a narrow directionalShadow to follow my main camera ?

Comment: I fixed up your sample a bit. I increased the shadowMapSize to 1024
(you were also only setting the width of shadowMapSize.. i set both now)
I switched to PCFSoftShadowMapping...


And added a little animation to show the effect better.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqZWQw

Comment: And yes... its a common technique to have a direction light follow either the camera, or the Object that is in focus.. like the car in a racing game, or the main character...

One problem you may run into is that moving the directional camera will cause the shadow edges to shimmer. You can avoid this effect by only moving the directional light, when its further away from the target object by a certain threshhold. I do this in a racing game I'm working on, and it works well.

Comment: Thanks.The point is to figure out when and where to set the light.It's very kind of you to offer me so mush help.

Comment: Edit: I UPDATE THE CODEPEN SO IT WORKS WITH LATEST 3JS:

https://codepen.io/manthrax/pen/BadMMmK